# Difference between "essential boundary conditions" and "natural boundary conditions"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

In a boundary value problem, what's the difference between "essential boundary conditions" and "natural boundary conditions"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://www.iitg.ac.in/engfac/rtiwari/resume/usdixit.pdf):

The two types of boundary conditions are used:

1. Essential or geometric boundary conditions which are imposed on the primary variable like displacements, and
2. Natural or force boundary conditions which are imposed on the secondary variable like forces and
   tractions.

Comment: Link says: _No preview available._

Comment: link works fine for me

Answer (score 5):

In the context of a variational problem for a functional

$$I[q]~:=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \! dt ~L(q,\dot{q},t),\qquad \dot{q}~\equiv~ \frac{dq}{dt},$$

defined on an interval $[t_i,t_f]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the types of boundary conditions (BC) are defined as follows:

1. *Essential/Dirichlet BC:* $\quad q(t_i)~=~q_i\quad\text{and}\quad q(t_f)~=~q_f.$
2. *Natural BC:* $\quad p(t_i)~=~0\quad\text{and}\quad p(t_f)~=~0.$

Here $$p~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} $$ is the canonical/conjugate momentum.

See also e.g. in my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218894/2451). The types of BC generalize to higher-dimensional regions.

Comment: What will be the natural Boundary Conditions if instead of $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ we have $L(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},t)$?

Comment: Hi @honey kumar. You might be interested in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/463573/2451).

Comment: Thankyou @Qmechanic