# Variations not vanishing at the boundary, Lagrangian.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

This might seem an obvious/stupid question, but I can't seem to find the way through it. Sorry in advance if anything I do is not very rigorous, I come from physics !

Say we have an action $S  = \int_a^b L(t,v,\dot{v})dt$. We are familiar with the process of minimazing this action using the calculus of variations, namely varying $v' = v+\epsilon\delta v$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ and $\delta v$ a sufficiently smooth function.

If we compute now $\delta S$ we get, by integration by parts $\delta S = \int_a^b (\partial_vL- \frac{d}{dt}\partial_{\dot{v}}L)\epsilon\delta v dt +\epsilon\partial_{\dot{v}}L\delta v(b)-\epsilon\partial_{\dot{v}}L\delta v(a)$

Now, usually, we set $\delta v(a) = \delta v(b) = 0$, and we get the Euler-Lagrange equation by requiring 0 variation for S. My question is, do we need to enforce vanishing of the variation of the boundary ? Is it something that is embedded somehow in the process of the calculus of variation, or is it just a reasonable choice ?

Could we, for example, set the derivative of the variation on the boundary instead ? If so, is it possible to still derive some kind of differential equation like the Euler-Lagrange one ?

My guess would be that $\delta v$ on the boundary vanishes is a requirement for this kind of development, but I am unable to justify it to myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ depends on

$$\dot{q}~\equiv~ \frac{dq}{dt},\tag{A}$$

it is necessary to impose boundary conditions (BCs) to have a well-defined [functional/variational derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) of the [action functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action)$^1$

$$I[q]~:=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \! dt ~L(q,\dot{q},t).\tag{B}$$

At each of the two boundary points $t_i$ and $t_f$, for each dynamical variable, there are [2 possibilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127):

1. Essential/Dirichlet BC.
2. Natural BC.

This is also e.g. explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218894/2451).
The nature of the variational problem may naturally select one of the two BCs for other reasons.

--

$^1$ In fact the variational problem (B) itself without BCs is often ill-posed. *Example:* The action for the [harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) without BCs is unbounded from below (and hence doesn't have a minimum).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link you posted. I read through, but I'm not sure I understand it, so I would need confirmation : 
- Is it right that the variational method is ill-defined if the B.C. of the problem do not make the surface term vanish ? In other words, do we require the B.C. to make the surface term vanish, to be able to apply the variational method ? In that sense, other B.C. than natural or Dirichlet would be "non-sensical" in the variational problem.

If this is correct, then that answers my question, but I might not have understood your answer well !

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look, as you have chosen $v$ as the *path with stationary action* and $v'$ as any neighbouring path, at the end points $A$ and $B$, both paths must coincide; else they cannot be deemed as possible paths of a particle going from $A$ to $B$. Just because they do not start and end at those points.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But in trying to find the stationary path, do I implicitly impose it's starting and finishing points ? I understand that in the case of a particle, it is the sensible thing to do. However, in the integral for the action there is only a statement of the starting and finishing times a and b.

 I am probably still missing something and I don't know if I'm very clear, but could you elaborate on your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The boundary conditions may be necessary to an extreme value. However, in the principle of least action,  motivated by optics (and other subjects), the boundary condition at $x_b$ is not restricted by the calculus of variation.