# Do boundary conditions matter in solving $y''-y = e^x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to figure out which functional $G$ is being minimized in $y''-y = e^x$. The Euler's equation is given by
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y'} - \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = 0
$$
So I'm trying to work backward. The $y''$ term could be obtained from $a(y')^2$, as $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y'} = y''$. Consider the second part of Euler's equation, we have the terms $by^2+c\cdot e^xy+d$. Comparing the guess with given equation, we have
$$
G = \frac{1}{2}(y')^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+e^x y+const.
$$
My question is do boundary conditions matter here?

Comment: Euler's equation is for integral functionals

Comment: Your Lagrangian $G$ looks correct but the action functional is $\int_a^bG(y(x),y'(x),x)\,dx$. Regarding boundary conditions please see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169655/variations-not-vanishing-at-the-boundary-lagrangian)