# variable endpoints - point-line distance

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The set-up: I was reading [2.3 First-order necessary conditions for weak extrema](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc/node1.html) and I got to the [variable endpoint section](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc/node32.html) and I got a bit confused and was hoping that someone could clarify. In [2.3.1](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc/node28.html) The author goes through minimizing the distance between two points (which I understand) by showing that the length functional (where $y=y(x)$) is

$$ I = \int_a^b ds = \int_a^b dx \sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2} $$
hence the Lagrangian is
$$ L = \sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}  $$.
We know that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}}\bigg) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0 $$
and it's plain to see that $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}L=0$, thus
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}}\bigg) = \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}} \bigg) = 0 $$
or 
$$ \frac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}} = C $$.
Thus
$$ \dot{y}=a=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}} $$.
Integrating it's plain to see that $y=ax + b $, which is just the equation for a straight line.

This I all get, but here's where I get lost and where my question comes in. When the author gets to variable endpoints, he brings up in [ex 2.4](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc/node32.html) that we should now consider the shortest path between a point and a vertical line:

[image: ex2.4]

I don't understand how this is different from what was done in the point-point distance situation... I'd just like it if someone could walk me through how the set-up is different and how we come to the conclusion a perpendicular line to the vertical line to the desired point is the shortest distance.

tl;dr: How does point-line distance differ from point-point distance, and how do we manipulate the Euler-Lagrange differential equation to express that? Walking me through this would be appreciated. Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with the proof of [Euler-Lagrange (EL) eq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). The main trick is to [integrate by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts). In particular, this produces boundary terms (BTs).

1. Now in the point-point distance minimization problem, these BTs vanish automatically because of essential/Dirichlet boundary conditions (BCs).
2. Not so for the point-line distance minimization problem. Instead, this induces a [natural](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127) BC.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I went through it slower and I think I figured it out for myself

Comment: Great. I hope I didn't spoiled the fun.