# Generalized boundary condition for Euler–Lagrange equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am dealing with a minimization of functional of the form:

$$I[f]=\sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \int_{\Omega}\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,f,f_1,f_2,f_{11},f_{12},f_{22}) \, d\textbf{x}$$
where $$\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2),~~~~~~~~~f_i=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},~~~~~~~~~f_{ij}=\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\,\partial x_j}$$ and two surfaces $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are bounded in 3D.

The general Euler-Lagrange equation for the similar case is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Several_functions_of_several_variables_with_higher_derivatives), however, they do not provide the general form for boundary conditions. In my problem, the boundary conditions in the matching point of two surfaces $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are unknown, and I should find the boundary conditions in addition to Euler–Lagrange equations to satisfy the stationarity.

I would like to know if anyone can introduce a reference for the complete proof of the Euler–Lagrange equation of the similar type which includes boundary conditions as well?

Comment: Do you really have *no* knowledge of the boundary conditions in the matching point? Shouldn't $f$ have a unique value in the point, i.e. the field on $\Omega_1$ and the field on $\Omega_2$ should be equal in the matching point?

Comment: Finding the boundary condition in matching point is what I am looking for in this problem. What I am missing is the boundary expression for two dimensions case with higher derivatives, similar to the term one can get from integration by parts in the one-dimensional case (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Statement). That's why I need to have the complete proof to see the similar terms which comes from probably similar integration by part.

Comment: You use $d\mathbf{x}$ for the area differential form. What notation do you prefer for the boundary differential form?

Answer (score 1):

That is a huge topic. Often in applications, the physical system dictates some boundary conditions (BCs). However OP seems to ask what BCs make the variational problem well-posed from a purely mathematical perspective?

1. Sufficient [essential](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127) BCs are obviously
   $$ \left. f\right|_{\partial \Omega_k}~=~0, \qquad \left. f_i\right|_{\partial \Omega_k}~=~0. $$
2. Other sufficient BCs include [natural](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127) BCs.
3. It is possible to impose different BCs on disconnected boundaries.
4. When the Lagrangian $\cal L$ is of some special form, the BCs can sometimes be relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
I[f] 
= \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \int_\Omega \mathcal L(\mathbf{x}, f(\mathbf{x}), \partial_i f(\mathbf{x}), \partial_j \partial_k f(\mathbf{x})) \, d\mathbf{x}.
$$

Doing a variation of $f$ we get
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda} I[f+\lambda\eta] 
= \frac{d}{d\lambda} \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \int_\Omega \mathcal L(\mathbf{x}, f+\lambda\eta, \partial_i (f+\lambda\eta), \partial_j \partial_k (f+\lambda\eta)) \, d\mathbf{x} \\
= \frac{d}{d\lambda} \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \int_\Omega \mathcal L(\mathbf{x}, f+\lambda\eta, \partial_i f + \lambda\,\partial_i\eta, \partial_j\partial_k f  +\lambda\,\partial_j\partial_k\eta)) \, d\mathbf{x} \\
= \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \int_\Omega \frac{d}{d\lambda} \mathcal L(\mathbf{x}, f+\lambda\,\eta, \partial_i f + \lambda\,\partial_i\eta, \partial_j \partial_k f  +\lambda\,\partial_j\partial_k\eta) \, d\mathbf{x} \\
= \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \int_\Omega \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial f} \eta + \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)} \partial_i\eta + \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \partial_j \partial_k \eta \right) d\mathbf{x}
$$

Rewriting the second term using integration by parts:
$$
\int_\Omega \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)} \partial_i\eta \, d\mathbf{x}
= \int_\Omega \partial_i \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)} \eta \right) d\mathbf{x} 
- \int_\Omega \partial_i \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)} \right) \eta \, d\mathbf{x} \\
= \oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)}  \eta \, n_i d{S}
- \int_\Omega \partial_i \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)} \right) \eta \, d\mathbf{x} 
$$

Rewriting the third term using integration by parts:
$$
\int_\Omega \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \partial_j \partial_k \eta \, d\mathbf{x}
= \int_\Omega \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \partial_k \eta \right) d\mathbf{x} 
- \int_\Omega \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \partial_k \eta \, d\mathbf{x} \\ 
= \int_\Omega \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \partial_k \eta \right) d\mathbf{x} 
- \int_\Omega \partial_k \left( \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \eta \right) \, d\mathbf{x}
+ \int_\Omega \partial_k \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \eta \, d\mathbf{x}
 \\ 
= \oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \partial_k \eta \, n_j d{S} 
- \oint_{\partial\Omega} \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \eta \, n_k d{S}
+ \int_\Omega \partial_k \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \eta \, d\mathbf{x}
 \\ 
$$

Thus we get
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda} I[f+\lambda\eta] 
= \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} 
\int_\Omega \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial f} - \partial_i \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_i f)} \right) + \partial_k \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \right) \eta \, d\mathbf{x} \\
+ \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} \left(
\oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)}  \eta \, n_i d{S}
+ \oint_{\partial\Omega} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \partial_k \eta \right) n_j d{S} 
- \oint_{\partial\Omega} \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \eta \, n_k d{S}
\right) \\
= \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} 
\int_\Omega \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial f} - \partial_i \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_i f)} \right) + \partial_k \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_k f)} \right) \right) \eta \, d\mathbf{x} \\
+ \sum_{\Omega=\Omega_1,\Omega_2} 
\oint_{\partial\Omega} \left(
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i f)}  \eta
+ \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_i \partial_k f)} \partial_k \eta 
- \partial_j \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_j \partial_i f)} \right) \eta \right) \, n_i d{S}
$$
Can you extract the equation and boundary conditions from this?