# Natural boundary conditions for a variational problem when $~f~$ is a function of higher order derivatives of $~y~$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I am not sure about the boundary conditions for a variational problem when $~f~$ is a function of higher order derivatives of $~y~.$

i.e. if we have: $~f(x,y,y',y'')~$ then what is the natural boundary condition in this case?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When the functional is of the form $$I[y(x)] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F \left(x,y(x),y'(x)\right) \,\rm{d}x~,$$then the natural boundary conditions are given in my answer of the following question: [What are natural boundary conditions in the calculus of variations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315027/what-are-natural-boundary-conditions-in-the-calculus-of-variations)
- If the functional involves higher derivatives of $~y(x)~,$ such as,
  $$I[y(x)] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F \left(x,y(x),y'(x),y''(x)\right) \,\rm{d}x$$then the minimum (or maximum) of $~I[y(x)]~$ satisfies the following Euler-Lagrange equation,
  $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}-\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right)+\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y''}\right)=0$$provided that $~y(x)~$ is subjected to the following essential or natural boundary conditions,

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{essential}& \text{natural}\\ \hline
y(x_1)=y_1 &\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y''}\right)=0~~\text{at}~~x=x_1 \\ \hline
y'(x_1)=y_1' & \frac{\partial F}{\partial y''}=0 ~~\text{at}~~x=x_1 \\ \hline \hline
y(x_2)=y_2 & \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y''}\right)=0~~\text{at}~~x=x_2  \\ \hline
y'(x_2)=y_2'& \frac{\partial F}{\partial y''}=0 ~~\text{at}~~x=x_2  \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: can you please tell me form where it is given in Simple way about natural boundary conditions in calculus of variations.

Comment: Most probably it's from a research paper. But I am unable to remember the exact source as it is an old post...