# What conditions do I need on a functional such that Euler Lagrange is consistent with boundary condition?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose we have a functional integral  between some end points and in order to find the function which optimizes it, I apply the Euler-Lagrange to the integrand. What I receive is a differential equation which I can put in the initial or final condition into. The doubt I have is, what conditions are required on the functional equation such that the curve I get in the end is consistent with both boundary condition?

Comment: The derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation assumes Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: what does that mean in English o_o

Comment: Ok I see, that regularity thing I said is there is assumed

Comment: It means boundary conditions of the form $y(a)=y_a,y(b)=y_b$. (I'm a little surprised you know anything about calculus of variations but have never heard of Dirichlet boundary conditions.)

Comment: My knowledge is basically from a physics context. Maybe I did hear of it before, but it didn't really click stick to me. @Ian

Answer (score 2):

It seems OP is putting the [cart before the horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart_before_the_horse). One cannot derive$^1$ the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) without assuming appropriate boundary conditions (BCs) in the first place.

For a first-order Lagrangian, there are the following possible BCs:

1. Essential/Dirichlet BCs,
2. Natural BCs,
3. Combinations thereof,

cf. e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2171559/11127).

--

$^1$ Of course one can always write down the EL equations, but without appropriate BCs, there is no guarantee that the EL equations are relevant for the variational problem at hand.