# How should I show that the stationary paths of this parametric functional are given by the solutions of the following equations?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $\gamma$ be a real constant with $\gamma^2\neq 1$ for the parametric functional $S[x, y]=\int_{0}^{1}[\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}-\lambda(x\dot{y}-\dot{x}y)]dt, \lambda>0,$ with the boundary conditions $x(0)=y(0)=0, x(1)=R>0$ and $y(1)=0$.

a) Show that the stationary paths of this parametric functional are given by the solutions of the equations $\frac{dx}{ds}+\gamma\frac{dy}{ds}=2(c-\lambda y)$ and $\gamma\frac{dx}{ds}+\frac{dy}{ds}=2(d+\lambda x)$, where $c$ and $d$ are constants and $s(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}dt$.

b) Show that $(\frac{dx}{ds})^2+2\gamma\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dy}{ds}+(\frac{dy}{ds})^2=1.$

Here's my work for part a):

Note that the associated Euler-Lagrange equations are $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\dot{x}})-\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\dot{y}})-\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y}=0$ where $\Phi=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}-\lambda(x\dot{y}-\dot{x}y)$ such that $\lambda>0.$

Then $\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\dot{x}}=\frac{2\dot{x}+2\gamma\dot{y}}{2\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}+\lambda y=\frac{\dot{x}+\gamma\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}+\lambda y, \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}=-\lambda\dot{y}.$

Similarly, I found $\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\dot{y}}=\frac{2\gamma\dot{x}+2\dot{y}}{2\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}-\lambda x=\frac{\gamma\dot{x}+\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}-\lambda x, \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y}=\lambda\dot{x}.$

From here, how should I take the derivatives and find $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\dot{x}}), \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\dot{y}})$ so I can find those Euler-Lagrange equations in order to solve for the stationary paths?

Comment: Would a solution using Mathematica be admissible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You again are on the right tack. It is about organizing the information. You don't take a further derivative. As you say,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \dot x} &= \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}=-\lambda \dot y = \frac{d}{dt}(-\lambda y),\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \dot y} &= \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}=\lambda \dot x = \frac{d}{dt}(\lambda x).
\end{align}
You integrate this already, since you know $\frac d{dt}$ of things are equal iff they differ by constants, so there exist $2c$ and $2d$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \dot x}=2c - \lambda y,\\
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \dot y}=2d - \lambda y.
\end{align}
Now plugging in your calculations for the left, you would get part a) as long as you notice that
$$
\frac{d}{ds}=\frac{dt}{ds}\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot x^2 +2\gamma\dot x\dot y+\dot y^2}}\frac{d}{dt},
$$
by the chain rule and the definition of $s$.

Now part b) has nothing more. It is just chain rule. Note that
$$
(\frac{dx}{ds})^2 + 2\gamma  (\frac{dx}{ds})(\frac{dy}{ds}) + (\frac{dy}{ds})^2 = (\dot x^2 + 2\gamma\dot x\dot y+\dot y^2)(\frac{dt}{ds})^{2}=\frac{\dot x^2 + 2\gamma\dot x\dot y+\dot y^2}{(\frac{ds}{dt})^{2}}=1,
$$
by the above.

(This question is so concrete, I wonder if there is more geometric meaning to it. It seems to be related to geodesics.)

Comment: So the Euler-Lagrange equations for $x$ and $y$ are $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\dot{x}+\gamma\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}+\lambda y)=0$ and $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\gamma\dot{x}+\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}}}-\lambda x)=0$? If so, then after integrating these two Euler-Lagrange equations, I'd be getting $\frac{\dot{x}+\gamma\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}+\lambda y=A$ and $\frac{\gamma\dot{x}+\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}-\lambda x=B$ where $A, B$ are constants. Are these correct?

Comment: Yes, but your first term $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \dot x}$ is longer, it has an extra $\lambda y$, that is why you call the constant $2c$.

Comment: So $\lambda y=2c$ and $-\lambda x=2d$?

Comment: We are a bit confused, just read my answer again. It is your whole long expression after d/dt is 2c. (Typing on a phone now)

Comment: I just don't understand where do $2c$ and $2d$ come from? After I move the $\lambda y$ and $-\lambda x$ to the other side, I got that $-\lambda y$ and $\lambda x$ on the right side of the equation but where do $2c$ and $2d$ come from? I can see that $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{ds}$ and $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{ds}$ but the denominator, $\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}$ moved to the other side should be multiplying $-\lambda y$ and $\lambda x$, right?

Comment: So the Euler-Langrange eqn is $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\dot x+\gamma \dot y}{\sqrt{\dot x^2+2\gamma\dot x\dot y+\dot y^2}} + \lambda y + \lambda y)=0$, so the whole function is $2c$ for some constant $c$. This would give one of the answer equations. The other one is similar.

Comment: Okay, so the $2\lambda y$ becomes $C-2\lambda y=2(C-\lambda y)$ to the right side then. What about the denominator of $\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}$ then? If we move that to the right side, then we have to multiply that to $2(C-\lambda y)$, right? How come I don't see it in $\frac{dx}{ds}+\gamma\frac{dy}{ds}=2(C-\lambda y)$?

Comment: $\frac{dx}{ds}$ is not $\dot x$, by chain rule, it is $\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot x^2 +2\gamma\dot x\dot y+\dot y^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}$, so there is no denominator to multiply through. The $\frac{dx}{ds}+\gamma \frac{d\gamma}{ds} = \frac{\dot x + \gamma \dot y}{\sqrt{\dot x^2+2\gamma \dot x\dot y + \dot y^2}}$. Nothing more to be done.

Comment: So $\frac{dy}{ds}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+2\gamma\dot{x}\dot{y}+\dot{y}^2}}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}?$

Comment: Right. By the way, these variational questions are quite nice, where did you get them? From a course you are taking?

Comment: Yes, the course is "Calculus of Variations and Advanced Calculus".

Comment: Now it made sense. I had many confusions earlier for this problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: May you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864915/how-should-i-show-that-the-equations-for-x-and-y-can-be-written-in-the-form ? I just found out that there was another part in this question and the given information from the question is the same. I need help on this last part of the question.